# Selecting off screen item in a spinner using Espresso

Tags: android, android-espresso

I have a `Spinner` with 20 items. The below code works if the `item` is displayed on the screen when user click on the spinner.

```
onData(allOf(is(instanceOf(SpinnerItem.class)), is(item))).perform(click());
```

For `item` that are requiring scrolling, the test will hit the below exception:

```
android.support.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'single click - At Coordinates: 719, -243 and precision: 16, 16' on view ' displaying data matching: (is an instance of SpinnerItem and is <Text>) within adapter view matching: is assignable from class: class android.widget.AdapterView'.
at android.support.test.espresso.PerformException$Builder.build(PerformException.java:83)
...
```

you can clearly see that the y-position is at -243 and therefore it couldn't perform the clicking. I tried to add `perform(scrollTo(), click())` but it's complaining the `scrollTo` doesn't work with onData.

Appreciate for any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I also have a large spinner and scrolling works fine. My code is the following:

```
onData(allOf(is(instanceOf(String.class)), containsString("5.1.3"))).perform(click());
```

Using espresso 2.2.2:

```
com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2
```

The only difference is that I use String in my adapter instead of custom class.
Maybe you should try to switch from `SpinnerItem` to `String` just to view will this error be gone or not?

Also problem can be in `is(SpinnerItem)`. You can try to write own Matcher for your SpinnerItems, like this:

```
public static Matcher<Object> withContent(final String content) {
    return new BoundedMatcher<Object, SpinnerItem>(SpinnerItem.class) {
        @Override
        public boolean matchesSafely(SpinnerItem myObj) {
            return myObj.content == content;
        }

        @Override
        public void describeTo(Description description) {
            description.appendText("with content '" + content + "'");
        }
    };
}
```

and use:

```
onData(withContent("5.")).inAdapterView(withId(R.id.contents_theory_listview)).perform(click());
```

This example suppose you have a `content` field in your item and you can check for its equality with the pattern.

I hope I gave you some ideas and they will help you.